# Trying to get data from mysql table via php with IN clause (favorites)

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, where-in

Here is how my table "User" looks:

```
Name Password Favorites

Test Test     1 2 3 4
```

And in my table "Data" I have

```
Comment ID
"Test"  2
```

I want the the user to be able to save a comment to its favorites, hence the first table, where I save all favorites in one row, so the table doesn't get too big. 
I try to get them all back by implode and IN clause. 
Right now it does not seem to work and I hope that maybe someone here could give me some useful input on how to conquer this problem :)

```
$favoritenstring = ($GET_["favoritenstring"]);

$query = "SELECT * FROM $table_id WHERE ID in ('" . implode("','",$favoritenstring) . "')";
```

Right now I am getting this error on the above query line: 
Invalid arguments passed

Comment: do a print_r on the query..does it look fine? does it work in mysql only?

Comment: I tried, but I don't get anything back, I guess its because of the error I get.

Comment: I don't think that `$favoritenstring` is an array perhaps?

Comment: favoritenstring is made up of: 1 2 3 4

Comment: Are you getting the `favoritenstring` from a separate query?

Comment: Is your array is like this `$favoritenstring = array('1','2','3')`?

Comment: Yes it is like this. When I print_r it, I get : (\'1\', \'2\', \'3\', \'4\')

Comment: Try this print_r(implode(',',$favoritenstring) )?

Comment: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your have to remove slashes from the string first:

```
$string = stripslashes($favoritenstring);
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table_id WHERE ID in " .$string;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I still get the same error message:  Invalid arguments passed

Comment: You will get this message until your array looks becomes `array('1','2','3')`

Comment: Well but my array looks like this :)

Comment: If it is string then just pass  ('1', '2', '3', '4') to query, don't use implode.

Answer (score 2):

Change This...

From

```
($GET_["favoritenstring"]);
```

TO

```
($_GET["favoritenstring"]);
```

Comment: Haha thank you, I put it on the wrong spot. Still didn't fix the problem thought, but thanks :)

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID in ('')

Comment: then try print_r($favoritenstring);

Comment: When I print_r it, I get : (\'1\', \'2\', \'3\', \'4\')

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table_id WHERE ID in ( ";

$myVars=explode($favoritenstring);
$numFavs=count(explode(' ', $favoritenstring));
for($i=0;$i<$numFavs;$i++)
{
    $query.=$myVars[$i];
    if($i<($numFavs-1))
    {
        $query.=", ";
    }
}

$query.=");";
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. However it says after the if "unexpected {"

Comment: You should _really_ use something like `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape the values instead of just concatenating them. Just taking them from the browser and putting them in a string is asking for sql injection.

Comment: @XCoderX Whoops, seem to have misplaced a `)` somewhere, probably under the lounge. Try that?

Comment: Thank you. However I get the error message: Warning: Wrong parameter count for explode()

Comment: @XCoderX *sigh* yeah, noob mistake on my part. Try that?